# HDFS file watcher

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, file-watcher

Can I have **file watcher** on **HDFS**?

**Scenario:**
The files are landing on HDFS continuously.I want to start a Spark Job once the number of files reached a threshold(it can be number of files or size of the files).

Is it possible to implement file watcher on HDFS to achieve this . If yes, then can anyone suggest the way to do it?What are the different options available? Can the Zookeeper or the Oozie do it?

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Spark Streaming has a similar function: in [FileInputDStream](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/FileInputDStream.scala#172-172)

Comment: Simple thing i can think is you can make use of unix command like this : hadoop fs -ls | wc -l

Comment: @YijieShen  Can you elaborate it more,please?

Comment: @user3484461 Yes..It will list all the files & it's details in the directory on the hdfs.I am trying to implement it as per your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, you can do this with Inotification. You just need to get the details of HDFS transaction thru inotifyier, to get better understanding read this [link](https://www.bectortapu.com/hdfs-file-watcher/).

Comment: I will try it .

Comment: Go ahead, let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hadoop 2.6 introduced `DFSInotifyEventInputStream` that you can use for this. You can get an instance of it from `HdfsAdmin` and then just call `.take()` or `.poll()` to get all the events. Event types include delete, append and create which should cover what you're looking for.

Here's a basic example. Make sure you run it as the `hdfs` user as the admin interface requires HDFS root.

```java
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, InterruptedException, MissingEventsException
{
    HdfsAdmin admin = new HdfsAdmin( URI.create( args[0] ), new Configuration() );
    DFSInotifyEventInputStream eventStream = admin.getInotifyEventStream();
    while( true ) {
        EventBatch events = eventStream.take();
        for( Event event : events.getEvents() ) {
            System.out.println( "event type = " + event.getEventType() );
            switch( event.getEventType() ) {
                case CREATE:
                    CreateEvent createEvent = (CreateEvent) event;
                    System.out.println( "  path = " + createEvent.getPath() );
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a blog post that covers it in more detail:

http://johnjianfang.blogspot.com/2015/03/hdfs-6634-inotify-in-hdfs.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

Oozie coordinator can do this. Oozie coordinator actions can be triggered based on data availability. Write a data triggered coordinator. The coordinator actions are triggered based on the done-flag. done-flag is nothing but an empty file. So when your threshold is reached write an empty file into the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread... In case, if someone wants to do this in `Scala`

```scala
import java.net.URI

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.client.HdfsAdmin
import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.inotify.Event.{AppendEvent, CreateEvent, RenameEvent}


object HDFSTest extends App {
  val admin = new HdfsAdmin( URI.create( "hdfs://namenode:port" ), new Configuration() )
  val eventStream = admin.getInotifyEventStream()

  while( true ) {
    val events =  eventStream.poll(2l, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    events.getEvents.toList.foreach { event ⇒
      println(s"event type = ${event.getEventType}")
      event match {
        case create: CreateEvent ⇒
          println("CREATE: " + create.getPath)

        case rename: RenameEvent ⇒
          println("RENAME: " + rename.getSrcPath + " => " + rename.getDstPath)

        case append: AppendEvent ⇒
          println("APPEND: " + append.getPath)

        case other ⇒
          println("other: " + other)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In case, if one wants to use an impersonated user... set env var: `HADOOP_USER_NAME=user-name`