# Can any nifi processor catch hdfs directory changes?

Tags: hadoop, apache-nifi

is there any way i can manage adding  deleting and updating flowfiles in my hdfs  directory after i delete or update them in my second   hdfs directory, i mean i want the same flowfile in directory 1 to change or be deleted aproprietly when  the flowfile with the same name is  changed in second directory? 
 **i tried to  use  listHdfs,fetchhdfs and  puthdfs  for  file  adding flowfile to second  directory**  but i can't manage  update and  delete  operations,
what  can i  do ?

1. Should i  use  hadoop  tools  for  it  or  it is  possible  to make  with nifi?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960186/hdfs-file-watcher